# Predicate logic equivalence problem: existential quantifier with conjunction

Tags: logic

can you share some light why below is correct by some examples?

$(\exists{xF}\wedge\exists{xG})\neq\exists{x(F}\wedge{G})$

Answer (score 0):

There exists a prime number. And there exists a non-prime number. But it's not the case that there exists a number that is both a prime, and a non-prime. More generally, let $F$ denote any formula such that $\exists x F$ and $\exists x \neg F$ are both true. Then letting $G:= \neg F$, we see that the left hand side is true, while the left hand side is false.

Comment: should we think the "x" in the left part of should be the same for both F and G  ?

Comment: Nope. Think about it algebraically. $\exists x F$ is either true or false. And $\exists x G$ is either true or false. So we can combine these truthvalues to get a truthvalue for $\exists x F \wedge \exists x G$. Obviously, this doesn't necessitate that the $x$'s be linked in any way.

Comment: so the formula : $\exists{x}F\wedge{G}$ is not the same as $\exists{x}F\wedge\exists{G}$ ? since the first one make the "x" shared between F and G  ?